# Regular grammar that generates a set of strings with an odd number of occurrences of a substring

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar

This is for a homework assignment. The prompt is:

> Give a regular grammar that generates the set of strings over {a, b,
>   c} with an odd number of occurrences of the substring bc.

I've been stuck on this for hours. So far I've tried:

S → aS | bS | bA

A → cA | cB

B → aB | bB | bC | λ

C → cC | cS

but this doesn't account for strings such as ccccbc. Then I tried:

S → A | B

A → aS | cS

B → bB | aS | bC

C → cC | cD

D → E | λ

E → F | G

F → aE | cE

G → bG | aE | bH

H → cH | cS

Which I think might be right but I'm not sure. Am I close/correct and if so how can I verify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started from scratch by designing a DFA to recognize the language, because this seemed the simplest approach:

[image]

If you work through it, you’ll see that this automaton is in state $2$ immediately after any odd number of substrings $bc$ and in state $0$ immediately after any even number of substrings $bc$.

Then I simply designed the grammar from the DFA:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aS\mid cS\mid bB_1\\
&B_1\to aS\mid bB_1\mid cC\mid c\\
&C\to bB_2\mid b\mid aC\mid cC\mid c\\
&B_2\to aC\mid a\mid bB_2\mid b\mid cS
\end{align*}$$

$S$ corresponds to state $0$, $B_1$ to state $1$, $C$ to state $2$, and $B_2$ to state $3$, and each production represents one transition in the DFA. For instance, the production $C\to bB_2$ represents the transition

$$2\overset{b}\longrightarrow 3\;,$$

and the production $B_1\to c$ represents halting in the acceptor state $2$ after the transition

$$1\overset{c}\longrightarrow 2\;.$$

Comment: So we were never shown this but it seems helpful. What does DFA stand for?

Comment: @JRTN: Deterministic finite-state automaton; there’s a brief introductory description [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Problem_Solving/Finite_state_machines). (There are probably much better ones, but I was able to find this one quickly.)